# 'docker stop' for crond times out

Tags: docker, cron

I'm trying to understand why my Docker container does not stop gracefully and just times out. The container is running `crond`:

```
FROM alpine:latest

ADD crontab /etc/crontabs/root
RUN chmod 0644 /etc/crontabs/root

CMD ["crond", "-f"]
```

And the `crontab` file is:

```
* * * * * echo 'Working'
# this empty line required by cron
```

Built with `docker build . -t periodic:latest`

And run with `docker run --rm --name periodic periodic:latest`

This is all good, but when I try to `docker stop periodic` from another terminal, it doesn't stop gracefully, the time out kicks in and is killed abruptly. It's like `crond` isn't responding to the SIGTERM.

`crond` is definitely PID 1

```
/ # ps
PID   USER     TIME  COMMAND
    1 root      0:00 crond -f
    6 root      0:00 ash
   11 root      0:00 ps
```

However, if I do this:

`docker run -it --rm --name shell alpine:latest ash` and
`docker exec -it shell crond -f` in another terminal, I can kill `crond` from the first shell with SIGTERM so I know it can be stopped with SIGTERM.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding an init process to the container (`init: true` in `docker-compose.yml`) solved the problem.

EDIT:  I read this https://blog.thesparktree.com/cron-in-docker to understand the issues and solutions around running cron in Docker.  From this article:

"Finally, as you’ve been playing around, you may have noticed that it’s difficult to kill the container running cron. You may have had to use docker kill or docker-compose kill to terminate the container, rather than using ctrl + C or docker stop.

Unfortunately, it seems like SIGINT is not always correctly handled by cron implementations when running in the foreground.

After researching a couple of alternatives, the only solution that seemed to work was using a process supervisor (like tini or s6-overlay). Since tini was merged into Docker 1.13, technically, you can use it transparently by passing --init to your docker run command. In practice you often can’t because your cluster manager doesn’t support it."

Since my original post and answer, I've migrated to Kubernetes, so `init` in docker-compose.yml won't work. My container is based on Debian Buster, so I've now installed `tini` in the Dockerfile, and changed the ENTRYPOINT to `["/usr/bin/tini", "--", "/usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh"]` (my entrypoint.sh finally does `exec cron -f`)

Comment: What is special about cron that it requires init: true to stop gracefully?  Is there a way for the image/container to solve the problem itself, instead of requiring a change in docker-compose?

Comment: @chrisinmtown  answer updated

Answer (score 0):

The key is that you cannot stop a pid=1 process in docker. It supposes that docker stops (or kills if it was launched with `--rm`).

That's why if you run `-it ... ash`, shell has pid 1 and you can kill other processes.

If you want your cron is killable without stopping/killing docker, just launch another process as entrypoint:

Launch cron after docker entrypoint (For example, run as cmd `tail -F /dev/null` and then launch cron `docker run -d yourdocker service cron start`)